# mockito - how to mock different behaviors for different arguments

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I want a simple mock to behave one way when called with a given argument, and another when called with everything else.

I've tried variations on this:

```
when(this.mockWebElement.findElement(not(eq(By.xpath("./td[1]"))))).thenReturn(this.mockWebElement);
when(this.mockWebElement.getText()).thenReturn("someString");

when(this.mockWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("./td[1]"))).thenReturn(dateMockElement);
when(dateMockElement.getText()).thenReturn("8/1/2014", "7/1/2014", "6/1/2014", "5/1/2014");
```

The call to `getText(By.xpath("./td[1]"))` always returns `"someString"`.  I've also tried `and(eq(any(By.class)), not(eq(By.xpath("./td[1]")))`.

Comment: where is your "not()" method coming from?  That does not appear in any version of Mockito that I am familiar with as a valid matcher.

Comment: http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/AdditionalMatchers.html

Answer (score 3):

Using your code as a basis, the following test passed for me:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

    @Mock private WebElement mockWebElement;
    @Mock private WebElement dateMockElement;

    @Test
    public void testX() throws Exception {
        when(this.mockWebElement.findElement(not(eq(By.xpath("./td[1]"))))).thenReturn(this.mockWebElement);
        when(this.mockWebElement.getText()).thenReturn("someString");

        when(this.mockWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("./td[1]"))).thenReturn(dateMockElement);
        when(dateMockElement.getText()).thenReturn("8/1/2014", "7/1/2014", "6/1/2014", "5/1/2014");

        WebElement w = mockWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("./td[1]"));
        String x= w.getText();
        assertEquals("8/1/2014", x);
    }
```

Since you haven't shown the rest of the test, I'm assuming the error is in the rest of your plumbing of the actual test setup and execution.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem I was having, so I assume you're right. Thanks for the backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use anyString() method as given below

```
 Mockito.when(mockedObject.someMethod(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(object1);
 Mockito.when(mockedObject.someMethod(Mockito.eq("anotherString"))).thenReturn(object2);
```

Comment: I do not see a `getInnerObject` method in the Mockito API.

Comment: Oh thats just my example, For you it is findElement()

Comment: This was my first thought, but this did not work for me.  Maybe it's because my argument calls another static method?